# Do you need to "remember" a consideration?

Tags: grammaticality

I wrote an email and sent it out for review to my manager. My text was:

> An important consideration is that you may see multiple objects for a single user.

My manager changed it to:

> An important consideration **to remember** is that you may see multiple objects for a single user.

Emphasis mine.

A consideration is defined as a careful thought. Do you need to remember a thought? If anything, I think you need to keep a thought in mind. In other words, consider a consideration.

Anyways... this can be reworded as `Something important to consider is...` but I am wondering, between the two of us, who is correct?

Comment: It is more common to treat considerations as things to be taken into account than as things to be remembered.

Comment: @SvenYargs Good point. I was going to say that the manager probably thought the sentence needed *remember*, which it did. *Consideration* almost did the job but not quite. But you don't need both those words. I would have said *It is important to remember that you may see multiple objects for a single user*. The manager was probably just being polite and not crossing out the redundant word.

Comment: [*One consideration to **remember***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+consideration+to+remember%22) is that version only gets 3 hits in Google Books, whereas [*one consideration to **bear in mind***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+consideration+to+bear+in+mind%22) gets 101 hits, and [*one consideration to **be taken into account***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+consideration+to+be+taken+into+account%22) gets 237.

Comment: @WS2 I think a consideration to remember is more appropriate when the information was previously known and you're asking the person to recall it.  If you look at FumbleFingers' comment you'll see it's not a very popular phrase. I went with "An important consideration to take into account...".

Comment: But I think @Sven Yargs comment is especially apposite. We are not *considering* anything - we are reminding people of what they might see.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing is a bit odd, but you can certainly remember a consideration. I'd phrase your sentence like this:

> It's important to remember to consider that you may see multiple objects for a single user.

However, the "remember" is almost entirely superfluous. In English, it's pretty normal to just say

> It's important to consider that you may see multiple objects for a single user.

*without* "remember". Or you might drop the "consider" instead:

> It's important to remember that you may see multiple objects for a single user.

In this case, they have roughly the same connotations.